# How to upgrade Magento in live site?

Tags: composer, magento2.3.4, cpanel, composer-update

I am working Magento2.3.4 in live site.
I'd like to upgrade Magento2.4.5.
so I cloned live site in subdomain.
In this case, how can I upgrade Magento?
I want to test in subdomain and then put in live site.
what is upgrade step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will do these steps to Upgrade to the  Magento2.4.5.

```
  Change the composer version from 1 to 2
       
     Change the PHP version to PHP 8.1
       
     Upgrade the version through Composer this is the rightway.
```

First test on this dev or staging environment and then live it on the Production.Because there will be many deprecation.